# Hive returns a non specific error : FAILED: SemanticException java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have the following query in HIVE, but it doesn't work

```
SELECT
newcust.dt , aspen.Probe , newcust.direction , aspen.VLan , sum(newcust.npacket), sum(newcust.nbyte), sum(newcust.nbytetcp), sum(newcust.nbyteudp), sum(newcust.byte_unknown), sum(newcust.pack_unknown), sum(newcust.byte_web), sum(newcust.pack_web), sum(newcust.byte_webapp), sum(newcust.pack_webapp), sum(newcust.byte_residential), sum(newcust.pack_residential), sum(newcust.byte_download), sum(newcust.pack_download), sum(newcust.byte_news), sum(newcust.pack_news), sum(newcust.byte_mail), sum(newcust.pack_mail), sum(newcust.byte_db), sum(newcust.pack_db), sum(newcust.byte_routing), sum(newcust.pack_routing), sum(newcust.byte_encrypted), sum(newcust.pack_encrypted), sum(newcust.byte_office), sum(newcust.pack_office), sum(newcust.byte_vpn), sum(newcust.pack_vpn), sum(newcust.byte_tunneling), sum(newcust.pack_tunneling), sum(newcust.byte_others), sum(newcust.pack_others), sum(newcust.byte_remoteaccess), sum(newcust.pack_remoteaccess), sum(newcust.byte_streaming), sum(newcust.pack_streaming) , sum(newcust.byte_chat), sum(newcust.pack_chat), sum(newcust.byte_voip), sum(newcust.pack_voip), aspen.CustomerName, aspen.General_NetworkPriority, aspen.SLA_CIR, aspen.SLA_EIR
FROM
 newcust INNER JOIN  aspen ON(  aspen.Probe = newcust.numsonde AND  aspen.VLan = substring(newcust.name1,1,instr(newcust.name1, '_')-1) )
WHERE
  newcust.numsonde = '1'
  AND  newcust.direction = '0'
  AND  newcust.dt LIKE '2012-01-20-%%%%'
  AND  COALESCE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(aspen.scd_end,'dd-MM-yyyy'),CAST(9999999999 AS BIGINT)) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(newcust.dt,'yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm')+cast((newcust.period * 360) as BIGINT)
  AND  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(aspen.scd_start,'dd-MM-yyyy') < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(newcust.dt,'yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm')+cast((newcust.period * 360) as BIGINT)
GROUP BY newcust.dt, aspen.Probe, newcust.direction, aspen.VLan, aspen.CustomerName, aspen.General_NetworkPriority, aspen.SLA_CIR, aspen.SLA_EIR, from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(newcust.dt,'yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm')+cast((newcust.period * 360) as BIGINT))
```

Hive returns the following error :

```
FAILED: SemanticException java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException. But there is no other explaination about the root of the problem.
```

Do you think the query is invalid or is it another "deeper" issue?

Comment: there should be a detailed log in jobtracker->job_id->failure/errors->log. paste it here if you can

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include all the fields which are there in the **select clause** are included in **group by clause**.